# 2010 Isuzu NQR diesel, 4KH1 ..CT........auto trans, codes and electric problems?

Tags: automatic-transmission, isuzu, nqr-diesel

It is a 2010 Isuzu NQR 4-cylinder diesel automatic transmission, 4KH1 CT model. The problem is no communication between the transmission & the main computer. Codes that I have number 1)..P0756, Shift Solenoid Valve 2 Performance.../Number 2)...P0776 Pressure Control Solenoid 2 Performance...Number(3) P0778 Pressure Control Solenoid 2 control circuit../ number 4) P0974 Shift  Solenoid1 Control Circuit, High Voltage../Number5) P0977 Shift Solenoid 2 Control Circuit, High Voltage.../ Number 6)P0983 Shift Solenoid 4 Control Circuit, High Voltage.../ Number 7) U2 104  Can Bus Counter Overrun. I am in Nashville, Tennessee, this vehicle is my home, I need a person with experience with electric problems.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Did this all of a sudden happen where you got all of the codes at once along with the issues? If so, I'd highly suggest you find where the wiring harness attaches to the transmission and check to see if it hasn't come unplugged for some reason. If that looks secure, start tracking it back towards the TCM/PCM to see if it's there's been a break somewhere. Nasty rodents have been known to do a number on those types of things.